# How to count SSE connections in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I am using this very simple endpoint for SSE in NestJS controller:

```
@Sse('/sse')
public async sse(): Promise<Observable<MessageEvent>> {
    return fromEvent([NodeStyleEventEmitter], [eventName]);
}
```

How can I easily tell, how many connections are open? I can include the res object to the call and watch when it ends while holding all active connections in a map. But there must be easier solution so I thought I will try to ask here.

Thanks